# Xamarin XAML DateTime and TimeSpan Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I can't seem to get the Binding working on a DateTime and TimeSpan field in my XAML. Everything appears to be OK, but the Picker's aren't loading the right values in. I'd also like to format the date and time slightly differently.

The date and time are coming in from a JSON response from an API.

I make this API call which maps to the model I posted above.

```
public static List<Race> GetRaces()
        {
            var raceList = new List<Race>();
            string APIServer = Application.Current.Properties["APIServer"].ToString();
            string Token = Application.Current.Properties["Token"].ToString();
            var client = new RestClient(APIServer);
            var request = new RestRequest("api/race", Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
            var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;
            raceList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Race>>(response.Content);
            return raceList;
        }
```

Here's the model.

```
public class Race
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime RaceDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan RaceStartTime { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int MaxEntries { get; set; }
    public int CurrentEntries { get; }
    public bool IsOpenForEntries { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
    public string Visibility { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a View Model which is being bound including these getters and setters.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using TechsportiseApp.API.Models;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using TechsportiseApp.API;

namespace TechsportiseApp.MainUI.Models
{
    public class RacesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool _visibility;
        public bool Visibility { get; set; }

        int _id;
        public int Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_id != value)
                {
                    _id = value;
                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        int _name;
        public int Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        string _description;
        public string Description
        {
            get
            {
                return _description;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_description != value)
                {
                    _description = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }

        string _contactEmail;
        public string ContactEmail
        {
            get
            {
                return _contactEmail;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_contactEmail != value)
                {
                    _contactEmail = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("ContactEmail");
                }
            }
        }

        string _contactNumber;
        public string ContactNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return _contactNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_contactNumber != value)
                {
                    _contactNumber = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("ContactNumber");
                }
            }
        }

        DateTime _raceDate;
        public DateTime RaceDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _raceDate;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_raceDate != value)
                {
                    _raceDate = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("RaceDate");
                }
            }
        }

        TimeSpan _raceStartTime;
        public TimeSpan RaceStartTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _raceStartTime;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_raceStartTime != value)
                {
                    _raceStartTime = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("RaceStartTime");
                }
            }
        }

        int _maxEntries;
        public int MaxEntries
        {
            get
            {
                return _maxEntries;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_maxEntries != value)
                {
                    _maxEntries = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("MaxEntries");
                }
            }
        }

        public int currentEntries { get; }

        bool _isOpenForEntries;
        public bool IsOpenForEntries
        {
            get
            {
                return _isOpenForEntries;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_isOpenForEntries != value)
                {
                    _isOpenForEntries = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsOpenForEntries");
                }
            }
        }

        bool _isPublished;
        public bool IsPublished
        {
            get
            {
                return _isPublished;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_isPublished != value)
                {
                    _isPublished = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    OnPropertyChanged("IsPublished");
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Race> RaceList
        {
            get
            {
                var racelist = RacesAPI.GetRaces();
                return racelist;
            }

        }

        int _racesIndex;
        public int RacesIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return _racesIndex;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_racesIndex != value)
                {
                    _racesIndex = value;

                    // trigger some action to take such as updating other labels or fields
                    Id = RaceList[value].Id;
                    Visibility = true;
                    OnPropertyChanged("RacesIndex");
                    OnPropertyChanged("Visibility");

                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                var changed = PropertyChanged;
                if (changed != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));               
                }
            }       
        }
}
```

And the XAML that is displaying is here.

```
<Label x:Name="labelRaceDate" 
       Text="Race Date" 
       IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
<DatePicker x:Name="datepickerRaceDate" 
            Date="{Binding RaceDate, StringFormat='{0:ddd d MMMM yyyy}'}" 
            Format="ddd d MMMM yyyy" 
            IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
<Label x:Name="labelRaceStartTime" 
       Text="Race Time" 
       IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
<TimePicker x:Name="timepickerRaceStartTime" 
            Time="{Binding RaceStartTime}" 
            IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
```

However, the result I always get is the default date and time. I have validated that the JSON response values are coming through correctly.

[image: Defaults]

Any ideas?

```
Here's the full XAML

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="TechsportiseApp.MainUI.Races"  Title="Races">
    <ScrollView  Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
    <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0">
            <Label x:Name="labelTest" Text="{Binding RaceDate}" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelInstructions" Text="Choose a race to view and edit, or create a new one." />
            <Picker x:Name="pickerRaceList" ItemsSource="{Binding RaceList, Mode=TwoWay}" Title="Pick a race" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedIndex="{Binding RacesIndex}" />
            <Label x:Name="labelName" Text="Name" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="entryName" Text="{Binding Item.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelDescription" Text="Description" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
            <Editor x:Name="editorDescription" Text="{Binding Item.Description, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
       <Label x:Name="labelContactName" Text="Contact Name" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="entryContactName" Text="{Binding Item.ContactName, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelContactNumber" Text="Contact Number"  IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="entryContactNumber" Text="{Binding Item.ContactNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Telephone" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelContactEmail" Text="ContactEmail" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
            <Entry x:Name="entryContactEmail" Text="{Binding Item.ContactEmail, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Email" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelRaceDate" Text="Race Date" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
                <DatePicker x:Name="datepickerRaceDate" Date="{Binding Item.RaceDate, StringFormat='{0:ddd d MMMM yyyy}', Mode=TwoWay}" Format="ddd d MMMM yyyy" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelRaceStartTime" Text="Race Time" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
                <TimePicker x:Name="timepickerRaceStartTime" Time="{Binding Item.RaceStartTime, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelMaxEntries" Text="Max Entries" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
                <Entry x:Name="entryMaxEntries" Text="{Binding Item.MaxEntries, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}" />
        <Label x:Name="labelCurrentEntries" Text="Current Entries" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
                <Entry x:Name="entryCurrentEntries" Text="{Binding Item.CurrentEntries}" Keyboard="Numeric" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}" IsEnabled="false"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelIsOpenForEntries" Text="Open For Entries" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>
            <Switch x:Name="switchIsOpenForEntries" IsToggled="{Binding Item.IsOpenForEntries, Mode=TwoWay}" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}" />
        <Button x:Name="saveButton" Text="Save" Clicked="OnSave" IsVisible="{Binding Visibility}"/>           
    </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can you please share how you set the data to properties? The code seems ok

Comment: I've updated the question to include it. I have an API call which is mapping the properties to the Race model. Then the List is populated from all the responses.

When I put a breakpoint in, I can see the response is the right Date.

Comment: do other values bind properly?  Are you sure it's just these two that are the problem?  Have you tried adding a Label and binding it to the date or time just to verify?

Comment: These views (Labels, date and time pickers) are in a ListView? I notice that you're using the type List<Race>. If it is, complet your  xaml code to reflect your real scenario, then I can write a code with the answer.  (sorry for the poor english)

Comment: @Jason Aha. Good catch. It's not loading into a label either...

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza It's a content page. I have a Picker which lists race. When I pick the race the form appear and loads all the data from the list into the form.

Comment: do you have your BindingContext set?  Are you sure the json values are getting correctly deserialized into your C# object?

Comment: @Jason the bindingcontext is set in the code-behind. Its not binding to any of the properties from the loaded Race object which represents a single item in the list.

            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new RacesViewModel();

So I think I need to work out why its not binding to the list items.

Comment: Then the `GetRaces()` in the question is not important. Where you set the values to the properties is, as @Jason mentioned, something related to bindingcontext.

Comment: Are you initializing the VM with the selected race?  Otherwise it will be empty.

Comment: I've added the full XAML.

I've nothing in place to Initialize the individual race in the ViewModel... How/where would I put that?

Comment: Updated to include the full ViewModel

Comment: FWIW, I've got the full code on GitHub. https://github.com/mattywarr/techsportise-app

Comment: So the idea is they will pick a race from the picker, and then the rest of the page will populate with details from that specific race?

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much it. Having now slept on it, I think my UI choice is pretty poor. I'd be better populating a ListView with the Races in a single view (and view model) then on picking from the list view show a contentpage with the details. I think that'll be a better UX so am going to try that route which should simplify the code a lot too.